Reading PETSc binary matrix in Python
I am trying to read a sparse PETSc matrix saved from a Fortran code into a binary file like so:
CALL PetscViewerBinaryOpen(PETSC_COMM_SELF, TRIM(ADJUSTL(filename)), FILE_MODE_WRITE, viewer2, ier)
CALL MatView(aa_symmetric, viewer2, ier)
CALL PetscViewerDestroy(viewer2, ier)

When I run the Fortran code single-threaded, all works fine and I can read the matrix without any issues using the following Python code:
import petsc4py
from petsc4py import PETSc

# Initialize PETSc
petsc4py.init(sys.argv)

# Create a viewer for reading the binary file
viewer = PETSc.Viewer().createBinary(filename, mode='r', comm=PETSc.COMM_WORLD)

# Create a matrix and load data from the binary file
A_petsc = PETSc.Mat().create(comm=PETSc.COMM_WORLD)
A_petsc.setType(PETSc.Mat.Type.AIJ)
A_petsc.setFromOptions()
A_petsc.load(viewer)

# Finalize PETSc
PETSc.Finalize()

However, when I run the Fortran code on more processors ("mpirun -n 2 my_exe"), I get the following error on the Python side:
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/Python/test_matrixImport_binary.py", line 80, in <module>
        A_petsc.load(viewer)   File "petsc4py/PETSc/Mat.pyx", line 2025, in 
petsc4py.PETSc.Mat.load petsc4py.PETSc.Error: error code 79 [0] MatLoad() at 
/home/lib/petsc-3.21.0/src/mat/interface/matrix.c:1344 [0] MatLoad_SeqAIJ() at 
/home/lib/petsc-3.21.0/src/mat/impls/aij/seq/aij.c:5091 [0] MatLoad_SeqAIJ_Binary() at 
/home/lib/petsc-3.21.0/src/mat/impls/aij/seq/aij.c:5142 [0] Unexpected data in file [0] 
Inconsistent matrix data in file: nonzeros = 460, sum-row-lengths = 761

How can I fix this?

Why PETSC_COMM_SELF?

I'm not sure, to be honest, this is what was done in another part of the code that I haven't written and I've just re-used the same code. I know for a fact that saving works fine - when I use an ASCII viewer, everything works as expected.

The saved output must differ in some way when once it can be opened and once it cannot.

It seems that the issue was on the export side, not on the PETSc side. I originally wrote the export routine for symmetric matrices but then applied it to one that's not symmetric, leading to confused addressing in the binary file. I hadn't caught it earlier because I was using my own ASCII import routine on the Python side that didn't care about symmetry. The snippet in the question should work fine. I am now using the following two functions that I think are a bit cleaner:
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, csr_matrix 
from petsc4py import PETSc

def readMat(filename, toScipy=False):
    viewer = PETSc.Viewer().createBinary(filename, mode='r', comm=PETSc.COMM_WORLD)
    A_petsc = PETSc.Mat().create(comm=PETSc.COMM_WORLD)
    A_petsc.setType(PETSc.Mat.Type.AIJ)
    A_petsc.setFromOptions()
    A_petsc.load(viewer)
    if toScipy:
        I, J, V = A_petsc.getValuesCSR()
        return csr_matrix((V, J, I)).tocoo()
    else:
        return A_petsc

def readVec(filename, toNumpy=False):
    viewer = PETSc.Viewer().createBinary(filename, mode='r', comm=PETSc.COMM_WORLD)
    v_petsc = PETSc.Vec().create(comm=PETSc.COMM_WORLD)
    v_petsc.setFromOptions()
    v_petsc.load(viewer)
    if toNumpy:
        return np.array(v_petsc)
    else:
        return v_petsc

